# Ajax request in Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, webserver

I am developing an extenion which makes an ajax request to a web server like this

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open(method, url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(data));
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() 
{ 
    if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 204) 
    { 
            //debugger;
            alert("Logged in");
            flag = 1;
            _callBack(xhr, xhr.readyState);
    }
}
```

And here i am able to logged in with status = 204 and now once i logged in i am trying to go for different directory for example www.example.com/index/enter with another ajax request in same extension but could not able to do so.

Comment: just let me know if didn't understand my question.

Comment: what specifically doesn't work? what errors do you see and from what parts of your code?

Comment: As my aim is that once i am authenticated to webserver, i should be able to transfer json data to my main server.

Comment: And when i am trying to provide my credentials it gives me a response status of 204 instead of 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're expecting the same HTTP response code? It's very likely that the server you're making requests to is sending a different response for a different request URL.

204 No Reponse = there is no response data

200 OK = there is data

Comment: Thanx Yoz! actually mistake was mine as i was accepting where there is no data in response.